# Applying ArcGIS Pro Raster Functions on multiple rasters

Tags: arcgis-pro, raster-functions

How do I apply raster functions (band arithmetics) on multiple rasters with one command, like a batch process?

Comment: What have you tried, have you looked at the help file?

Comment: Yes i did. There is nothing mentioned about my problem

Answer (score 1):

The function "Band Arithmetic", falls under the [Cached Raster function](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/raster-functions/cached-raster-function.htm)

For your objective, you can use the [Raster Functions Batch Editor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/raster-functions/raster-functions-batch-editor.htm)

**Note:** This function is only supported when added to the function chain for an item in the mosaic dataset. It is not valid to add this function to the mosaic dataset's function chain or to the function chain on a layer.

Comment: Okay. I have to mosaic them first, right?